# How to fix "None of the audience values matched the tokenEndpoint Alias https://172.28.1.101:9444/oauth2/token"?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am setting up WSO2 API Manager and secure API with self contained access token (JWT). Here's [a link](https://medium.com/wso2-learning/how-to-protect-your-apis-with-self-contained-access-token-jwt-using-wso2-api-manager-and-wso2-75673d8a4686) i followed to protect your APIs with self contained access token (JWT) using WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server.

I am getting JWT token from the WSO2 identity server. But when I tried to get access token using the JWT token from WSO2IS, I am getting following error

**HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

**X-Frame-Options: DENY**

**X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff**

**X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block**

**Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2019 11:53:42 GMT**

**Content-Type: application/json**

**Content-Length: 146**

**Connection: close**

**Server: WSO2 Carbon Server**

**{"error_description":"None of the audience values matched the tokenEndpoint Alias https://172.28.1.101:9444/oauth2/token","error":"invalid_grant"}**

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using Oauth 2 Authorization code grant type. You have taken a JWT and then using that you are trying to get the access token. In your service provider configuration under Inbound Authentication Configuration under OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration if you click edit there is a checkbox field named Enable Audience Restriction. Add the https://172.28.1.101:9444/oauth2/token as an audience. Then try the flow. For more information refer

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Inbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider

OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. But this couldn't help me. I am getting same error on adding audience as you mentioned and following the doc you mentioned.